# JavaScript function not called at onclick button in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio

I am learning JavaScript and CSS and made a test project in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. The problem that I have is, the function changeTitleCSSStyle isn't called when using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. At online editor https://js.do/ and in Google Chrome browser the function call works properly. My code:

index.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css">
    <title>JavaScript and HTML</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
        function changeTitleCSSStyle() {
            alert("Aanroep");
            var title = document.querySelector("#mainTitle");
            title.style.color = 'black';
            title.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            title.style.border = "5px dashed red";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="mainTitle">My home page</h1>
    <p>This is an example of interactivity between JavaScript and the HTML content of a document.</p>
    <button onclick="javascript: changeTitleCSSStyle();">Change style</button>
</body>
</html>
```

default.css

```
h1 {
    color: red;
    background-color: lightGreen;
    border: 12px solid violet;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

p, h1 {
    font-family: cursive;
}

p, img, button {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: are you doing a web form project in VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it doesn't work when using VS. Maybe inline click events are not supported for some reason.

Perhaps it works if you try setting the event in your script itself like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaScript and HTML</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script>
    function changeTitleCSSStyle() {
        alert("Aanroep");
        var title = document.querySelector("#mainTitle");
        title.style.color = 'black';
        title.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        title.style.border = "5px dashed red";
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var button = document.getElementById('change_style_button')
        button.addEventListener('click', function(){
            changeTitleCSSStyle()
        });
     });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="mainTitle">My home page</h1>
    <p>This is an example of interactivity between JavaScript and the HTML content of a document.</p>
    <button id="change_style_button">Change style</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<button onclick="changeTitleCSSStyle();">Change style</button>
```